# Proving the Completeness of Propositional Deductive Calculus?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Question: Prove the completeness of propositional deductive calculus using only theorems of sentential logic.

I know that the common way to prove completeness is to use the Model Existence Theorem (where every consistent set of formulas is satisfiable).

But is there a way to prove completeness without using consistency and satisfiability?

Comment: What are these “theorems of sentential logic” that we’re allowed to use?

Comment: @MarkSaving I suppose any theorem that does not belong to first-order logic? It is not specified, but the instructions required that we do not use satisfiability/consistency.

Comment: See e.g [Completeness Theorem of Classical Propositional Logic](https://akaposi.github.io/proplogic.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be the set of atomic propositions. Let $S$ be the set of propositions formed from the atomic propositions $X$ using the usual logical operators ($\top$, $\bot$, $\land$, $\lor$, $\neg$, and $\to$), and let $\pi : S \to B$ be the Boolean algebra formed by taking $S$ and quotienting by logical equivalence.

Consider $\Gamma \subseteq S$. Note that for all $\phi$, $\Gamma \vdash \phi$ if and only if there are $s_1, \ldots, s_n \in \Gamma$ such that $s_1, \ldots, s_n \vdash \phi$. This in turn holds if and only if there are $s_1, \ldots, s_n \in \Gamma$ such that $s_1 \land \cdots \land s_n \vdash \phi$. This in turn holds if and only if $\pi(\phi)$ is in the filter generated by $\pi(\Gamma)$.

So $\Gamma \vdash \phi$ if and only if $\pi(\phi)$ is in the filter generated by $\Gamma$.

Now suppose that $\Gamma \nvdash \bot$. Since $\Gamma \nvdash \bot$, the filter generated by $\pi(\Gamma)$ is proper (ie does not contain the minimal element $\pi(\bot)$). Every proper filter can be extended to an ultrafilter by the ultrafilter lemma, so take an ultrafilter $U$ such that $\pi(\Gamma) \subseteq U$. Every ultrafilter arises as $f^{-1}(\top)$ for some Boolean algebra homomorphism $f : B \to 2$, so take some $f : B \to 2$ such that $U = f^{-1}(2)$. In particular, we have $f|_X : X \to 2$. Note that $f \models \Gamma$.

This proves that every consistent propositional theory has a model.

Now suppose that $\Gamma \models \phi$. Then $\Gamma \cup \{\neg \phi\}$ does not have a model, and therefore $\Gamma \cup \{\neg \phi\} \vdash \bot$. Therefore, $\Gamma \vdash \phi$. This is the completeness theorem.